# Wordpress Woocommerce texts too close to each other

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have built my online shop in Wordpress, theme Ellie, and using Woocommerce plugin.

Issue is that the texts "View Cart" and "Checkout" are too close to each other in 2 different places: Footer and Cart widget on Shop page. Something wrong there.

**Shop page**

[image: Shop page]

**Footer**
[image: Footer]

https://senjacosmetics.com/shop/

Really happy if you can help! I tried to research this but didn't find anything. I'm not a developer so cannot proceed on my own.

Answer (score 1):

This is just small css issue. You can easily solve it by adding some css rule.
You can add following css rule in your theme's style sheet or if your theme supports custom css, then via that feature.

```css
.woocommerce-mini-cart__buttons a.checkout{margin-left:15px;}
```

"*woocommerce-mini-cart__buttons*" is the class assigned to 'p' tag which contains both the links. "*checkout*" is one of the class assigned to the 'Checkout' link.

You can change the value of '15px' to anything you want depending on how much space you want between the two links.

Following is screenshot for your reference. I added the css rule to checkout link in developer console.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: god damn tourists.

Comment: Thanks Stender. Appreciate it.